# It's is possible to do a insert on a mapplet without SQL transformation

Tags: informatica-powercenter

It's is possible to do a insert on a mapplet without SQL transformation? Like in an expression?

Thanks

Comment: Trying hard, yet I can't understand your question. Can you show some example of what you're trying to do? What is the issue? What doesn't work? What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is ‘no’

A mapplet cannot contain a target, it CAN contain a source, which is kind of counter intuitive I suppose :)

You must always have at least one port going out of the mapplet, but as you suggest, it is possible to do ‘writing’ anyway, using a sql-trans.

Personally I prefer not to do so, and let all the writing happen immediately after the mapplet, since the sql trans is rather difficult to debug, and logging metadata in the repository is non-existing.